# Logic behind modified subset function - from exhaustive recursion to backtracking?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have looked across the backtracking problems here but none have showed the transition from an exhaustive recursion approach to a subset sum problem to one using backtracking.

We start with a CanMakeSum function which takes a set and determines whether this it can produce a sum or not.

The code WAS exactly the same problem as this question: [Recursion: Understanding (subset-sum) inclusion/exclusion pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642283/recursion-understanding-subset-sum-inclusion-exclusion-pattern).

Now need to rewrite this code:

1. at each step, I need to choose one of the remaining elements to add to the subset and recur from there. That is why the below code takes a different approach, and is a REWRITE from the above code (it is a different approach).
2. have to change the function to print all the members that sum to the target.
3. change the function to report the count of all possible subsets.

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. I'm just confused about the logic.

```
int main () {

while (true) {

    if (response == 0) break;

    cout << "Please type in integers. When finished, press 0: ";
    response = GetInteger();
    sumvector.add(response);

}

cout << "Please enter a target sum: ";
int target = GetInteger();

if (CanMakeSum(sumvector, target)) {
    cout << "Yes, a sum exists in this vector." << endl;
} else {
    cout << "No, a sum does not exist in this vector." << endl;
}

return 0;
}

bool CanMakeSum(Vector<int> & nums, int targetSum) {

if (nums.isEmpty()) { 

    return targetSum == 0;

} else {

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {

        int element = nums[i];
        Vector<int> rest;
        rest.add(element);
        nums.removeAt(i);

        if (CanMakeSum(rest, targetSum - element)) {

            cout << "These numbers, in rest, make up the targetSum." << endl;
            return true;

        }
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There seems to some misunterstanding; in the code you have provided the link for, the solving function `subsetSumExists` does not loop ever the entries, but considers only the first element `a` and distiguishes two cases: in the first case, `a` is not _not_ chosen to be included in the sum, while in the secon case `a` _is_ chosen. Your approach seems to be totally different.

Comment: Hi @Codor, thanks for having a look. Perhaps that was confusing to add without explaining it. The first code shows in/out exhaustive recursion whee both cases are considered. In the second code, I need to change the first code (so rewrite the function so that at each step, I need to choose one of the remaining elements to add to the subset and recur from there). Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Codor Have just changed the above to reflect my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, I see - your approach seems valid, so in each recursive step there is actually an item chosen.

Comment: @Codor When I compile it, I get stack overflow, so there's probably an error in this logic somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in your code. For each recursive call, there will only one element in `rest`, namely `element`. I believe you would like to have `rest` initialized to the entire input `nums` *without* `element`. Furthermore, your base case seems to make no sense; the recursion should end when `targetSum` is zero, provided that only nonnegative arguments are valid, and the return value should be `true`. In the loop, you should return `false` when no suitable items can be chosen.

The actual selection of subsets has to be maintained with an auxiliary data structure, say a `Vector<int>`, which can be global or passed by reference into each recursive call and be filled with the chosen items. In the base case, its content would have to be printed, but after each recursive call the respective chosen item would have to be removed again. The algorithm would then exhaustively enumerate every suitable subset.

The overall approach might look like the following. Assume we have some global `Vector<int> partial_solution`, which initially is empty

```
bool CanMakeSum(Vector<int> & nums, int targetSum) {
    if ( 0 == targetSum ){
        // todo: output partial_solution
        return true;
    } else {

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        int element = nums[i];
        if ( element >= targetSum ){ // check whether element can actually be chosen
            Vector<int> rest;
            // todo: initialize rest to contain nums without element
            // todo: add element to partial_solution
            if (CanMakeSum(rest, targetSum - element)) {
                return true;
            }
            // todo: remove element from partial_solution
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. Is there any way you could add some pseudocode to help me understand your points more clearly -- just to make sure I have it clear?

Comment: Okay, this should work, hovever I have not actually tried it, but the idea should become clearer.